# Responsive email without media query or calc() function [both Office 365 and the new Outlook.com]

Tags: css, responsive-design, html-email, calc

How can I hide an image when the screen gets smaller without using media query or the calc() function in my responsive email template?

I have to use inline styling because I cannot add CSS classes or use style block in any way (This is due to the nature of a customized app for sending mail), so media query isn't an option for me nor does calc() function work in outlook - it simply removes it.

I've followed the guidelines of Fab Four technique (https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-fab-four-technique-to-create-responsive-emails-without-media-queries-baf11fdfa848/#.mewdyxnz5) but it didn't help me.

Comment: You can include a `<style>` block in the `<body>`. I'm not sure if the latest Outlook.com/365 will remove it, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the `@media`, but, you can include the `<style>` block in the `<body>`.

For the sake of completeness/others, you might do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .hideMobile { display:none!important; }
}
</style>
<img class="hideMobile" src="..." width="xxx" />
```